# How to create M-dot site?

Tags: mobile, seo, subdomain

I'm trying to figure out how to create an M-dot site. My current site is already responsive and I'm using only 1 URL which is `cambria.com` and since Google goes to mobile-first indexing I'm trying to create an `m.cambria.com` to apply the best practices for mobile-first indexing and since it tells something about Separate URLs, here's the link: [Best practices for mobile-first indexing](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-first-indexing#desktop).

My questions is to create a separate URL for mobile do I have to copy all the original files and create a new folder for mobile and set the domain that access this folder to `m.cambria.com`?

Is that the right way to create a M-dot site?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a site which is like " m.sitename.com ", then you should make a new subdomain and point it to the directory where you have keep the absolute mobile version of you site, not responsive.

But, for it to work you also first need to make some changes in .htacess file.

**OR**

You need to resolve media queries with JAVASCRIPT or with anyone of programing script that if the size of the screen is lesser than the desktop then the  main site should redirect to the m.sitename.com version of your website.

For conclusion it is really easy to do so. But if you have a responsive website I don't think you need to do anything with your current site.

Comment: I see thanks this helps a lot

Comment: @JaeEun welcome